# what is $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}{(\cos(z))^{1/z^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The suggestion was to use L'Hospital's rule but I couldn't see how to apply it.

I tried manipulating the term to $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \exp(1/z^2\ln|º\cos(z)|+i\arg(\cos(z)))=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \exp(i\arg(\cos(z))$ and I also don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(\cos z)^{1/z^2}=[1+(\cos z-1)]^{1/z^2}=\left\{[1+(\cos z-1)]^{\frac{1}{\cos z-1}}\right\}^{\frac{\cos z-1}{z^2}}.
$$

The par between $\{\cdot\}$ goes to $e$, since $\cos z-1\to0$ ($z\to0$). So you can apply L'Hôpital to the exponent $\frac{\cos z-1}{z^2}$.

But if you remember that $1-\cos z\sim \frac{z^2}{2}$ as $z\to 0$, then $$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\cos z-1}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{-z^2/2}{z^2}=-\frac{1}{2},$$
so your limit is $$\lim_{z\to0}(\cos z)^{1/z^2}=e^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt e}.$$

Comment: why is 1-cos(z) similar to (z^2)/2? Is that from the taylor expansion?

Comment: You can apply L'Hopital or you can use Taylor expansion: $\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\big[\cos(z)\big]^{\frac 1 {z^2}}\implies \log(y)=\frac 1 {z^2}\log\big[\cos(z)\big]$$

Now, using Taylor series
$$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+O\left(z^6\right)$$
$$\log\big[\cos(z)\big]=-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^4}{12}+O\left(z^6\right)$$
$$\log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z^2}{12}+O\left(z^4\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}-\frac{z^2}{12 \sqrt{e}}+O\left(z^4\right)$$